# Volvo S40 2008 damaged driver side mirror

Tags: volvo, mirrors, s40

I noticed today that the driver side mirror was damaged. It's still functional: the mirror adjustment controls work and the blinkers on it work.

I am worried about increased wear and water damage when it rains (luckily it's summer).

[image]

[image]

It seems to me that the only thing missing is the plastic cover, but I'm not sure.

**Which parts do I need to get? How do I install them?**

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it is just the cover, found [here](http://www.volvopartswebstore.com/showAssembly.aspx?ukey_assembly=1331804&ukey_make=865&ukey_model=12008&modelYear=2008&ukey_category=7854) for around $110 USD. It appears just to snap on, so I'd ensure that all of the securing clips on the mirror are intact before trying to attach it.

Comment: Thats 170$ with shipping for some plastics... How bad is it if I put some plastic bags and tape? Will it survive the rain?

Comment: IMO, yes you can cover it with a plastic bag. Those covers are not 100% sealed anyway (as you can see by the dirt and dust). You can also look for a second hand one at a salvage yard or on eBay.

Comment: Also keep in mind the plastic is going to be unpainted (or possibly a different color if you buy used), so if you want it to match you'll need to factor in the cost of that as well.